# pdfbox save acroform as normal pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to fill out pdf acroform. I fill in the fields:

```
acroForm.getField(key).setValue(value);
```

Then I set fields as read only:

```
acroForm.getFields().forEach(f->f.setReadOnly(true));
```

I'm saving it. It looks nice in google chrome, but in edge when I click print button fields which I fill are blank. My full code:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + templatePath));
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
if(acroForm != null){
    fieldValueMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        try {
            acroForm.getField(key).setValue(value);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Error:  no such field in AcroForm");
        }
    });
    acroForm.getFields().forEach(f->f.setReadOnly(true));
}
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

pdfDocument.save(outputStream);
pdfDocument.close();
return addSecuredResource(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

I was trying to use flatten() function, but it doesn't work(both on chrome and edge I have blank fields). I think it is due to that pdfbox saves pdf still as acroform. How can i save it as normal pdf with inserted values for fields?

UPDATE:

How my acroform pdf look(opened in browser, no pdfbox use):

[image: how my acroform pdf look(opened in browser, no pdfbox use)]

I can edit it in a browser:

[image: editing acroform]

In chrome, after creating new document it looks ok without printing and with printing mode:

- Before going to print mode:
  [image: before going to print mode]
- print mode
  [image: print mode]

In edge

- it looks ok without printing mode:
  [image: edge]
- but in print mode i dont have my field filled (with value):
  [image: edge print mode]

Comment: *"I think it is due to that pdfbox saves pdf still as acroform. How can i save it as normal pdf with inserted values for fields?"* - the **AcroForm** structure *is* a part of a *normal pdf*. Thus, your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Hmm so i would like to have in Edge after clicking print button my fields filled.

Comment: I updated my question, I think it is clear now.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Please read the javadoc of PDAcroForm.getFields ().

Comment: I'm using 2.0.9 version. PDAcroForm.getFields() from javadoc: This will return all of the documents root fields. - i know it, in my documents there is no tree structure

Comment: Please try again with 2.0.10. That one has a `flatten()` bug fixed. Please share your PDF and edit your code so that it is self-working. `fieldValueMap` is missing in your current code.

Comment: If the issue still persists, please share your PDF and edit your code so that it is self-working as already @Tilman requested. Otherwise, please either post an answer with the solution or remove the question.

Comment: was this problem solved?